# Correct rewrite rule creating internal server error

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here was my initial issue.
Some people are doing links to my site, but with incorrect urls, generally adding weird caracter after the url.

so, for exemple, instead of linking to :
www.example.com/hello.php
they link to :
www.example.com/hello.php+fiat
then making a 404 error occuring.

I did create a rewrite rule like this that is working like a charm :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-/_]*\.php).* $1 [L]
```

i tried that 2 with the same behaviour (working fine)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php).* $1
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php).*$ $1
```

everything after .php is remove and then directing to the right url.
question mark is not an issue in the rewrite, meaning i have a lot of pages with xyz.php?id= and i want to keep these as they are.

but now, for an obscure reason,
when i type a url that doesn't exist like :
example.com/toto/index.php
I have a 500 internal server error instead of the usual 404 page.
but if i remove my rule, then i have the 404 page again as usual.

if it can help, the only rule that is making Apache crashing is that one :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php).* $1 [R=301,L]
```

Any idea ? (on Apache 2.2)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php).* $1 [R=301,L]
```

Will very likely create infinite loop as any URL that doesn't have anything after `php` will match and redirect to itself, as the sequence following `.php` is optional.

You should change the final `.*` to `.+`

Comment: Of course ! Thanks a lot ! 
it's working 100% fine when i do : RewriteRule ^(.*\.php).* $1 [L] but if I put the R=301 in it, RewriteRule ^(.*\.php).* $1 [R=301,L] then it's adding my server path between the domain name and the name of the file.

Comment: i've just added the / before $1, then not adding my server path between the domain name and the name of the file if the R=301 was set (but working fine otherwise)

Comment: Yes, by default the target is assumed to be a file path, not a URI. You could try to use the `[PT]` flag too, see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt

Comment: Thanks for the extra answer :-)